# Using Drupal 7 User Information as Authentication in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, doctrine-orm, drupal-7, authentication

I have a Drupal 7 website which serves as a company's intranet. I also have a related system of forms which run outside of Drupal. I plan on re-designing this forms system under Laravel 4 (using Doctrine 2 as my ORM as opposed to Eloquent).

When a user is logged into Drupal 7, he/she should also be able to pop over to the Laravel system and have instant access to the outside forms. So the question is: **How do I get Laravel to grab a Drupal 7 user's credential (session ID and session hash) and use it as authentication in that system?** Is this even possible? Then obviously as soon as the user logs off Laravel needs to know this and redirect the user back to sign in with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Establish a connection to the Drupal 7 database inside of Laravel's app/config/database.php file:

```
'drupal' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'dpl',
    'username'  => 'user',
    'password'  => 'pass$5',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Then from within a function (in this case I made a class called DrupalAuthorization), use Laravel's DB facade to call that newly-created connection like so:

```
$users = DB::connection('drupal');
```

Finally, simply use the Laravel select method to run a query gathering the Drupal user's session information:

```
$users = DB::connection('drupal')->select("SELECT uid, sid FROM d7_sessions WHERE hostname = ? AND uid > ? ORDER BY uid DESC", array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], 0));
```